# Is it possible to manipulate the scrollbar thumb height regardless of the content?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so this one's a bit tricky. For context, I'm working on a table using https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/ and I can know in advance the size of the sample I will have to show.

Anyhow, I need to be able to show the user the whole sample of records just using the scrollbar. What I mean by this, is that I don't want to load 100k records, but rather calculate the corresponding height of the scrollbar thumb, based on said number of records, so that if I have 5 records, there should be no scrolling, but if I have 100k records, then the scrollbar thumb should be quite small.

[image]

I was able to achieve this behavior by pre-loading N records to the table, however this isn't desirable because of the performance impact of loading an 100k array. Another alternative would be to resize the table knowing the size of 1 row, and multiplying it by 100k.

So to sum it up: is there a way to manipulate the scrollbar thumb size ignoring the table content? Maybe doing something funky with the shadow dom, or resizing the table size.

Comment: The result you are trying to achieve sounds very similar to infinite scrolling, which ag-grid supports: https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/infinite-scrolling/

Comment: Yeah, I have that implemented, but it isn't actually what I'm looking for. Infinite scrolling implies a sequential loading of the whole sample, IE I start from the first record and need to scroll down until I reach the end. What I want to achieve would grant me random-access to any record. But thanks for your input!!